# Testing directories like snapshots

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests

I know it's possible to do snapshot testing for UI components in React, but I was wondering if it is possible to compress a folder and run test against it sort of like asserting if snapshots match. 
I am currently writing unit tests for an API written in nodejs, and I'd  like to ensure that the content of a particular folder is not tampered with as it contains third party code that wasn't installed with npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may need a custom solution built just for that specific

> folder and run test against it sort of like asserting if snapshots match

I would say, that you can leverage your VCS like [git-difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt--d) and simply assert the `--dir-diff` output according to your domain needs.